# My tv loses the signal while playing retropie

Tags: display, retropie, emulation

I have got Retropie working and was testing an PS1 emulator. All was fine for 10 minutes or so, then lost the signal to the TV. After restarted the RPi and loaded up the emulator again the same problem reoccurred. I just seen to be losing the signal between the RPi and the TV!  Does anyone have any ideas as to what is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange network. How is the TV connected, by HDMI or Composite Video?  What were you playing on the emulator at the time - and had it been idle for a while?

Comment: Can you tried other emulator?

Comment: its connected by hdmi. was playing colin mcrae rally. it was brand new out of the box for an hour or so. im a total noob here and have no keyboard and mouse to use at the moment. only other thing connected was a wireless adapter for xbox remote. the emulator was working perfectly for awhile but then it just showed up as no signal.

Comment: What color are the leds on the Pi when this loss of signal occurs? And is it a complete loss of signal such that the tv will no longer detect the inptut or is the screen just going black or showing artifacts?

Comment: This happens to me on a LG television using HDMI and a raspberry Pi 4. It does not happen if I am seeing a movie for example, only on retropie. I have also monitored the CPU and GPU temperatures,which was my main suspect, and they aren't much higher than when it's working. Besides, the raspberry does not shutdown, I can still connect to it using ssh

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting it's not just a display issue, and that it's overheating and shutting down, or otherwise crashing.

Test this by attempting to connect to or ping the Pi over the network; if it were simply a display issue, these connections would still work.

If it's crashing or overheating, 
Test heat by venting, using a program to check temps, or slapping a tiny heatsink on it.
Check for crashing by reading in /var/logs for the appropriate time-stamps.

Comment: would it take much to overheat a pi? im a total noob

Comment: It doesnt take much to overheat a Pi. Theyre not workhorse systems and emulation can push them pretty hard depending. Most RetroPie setups have 2 heatsinks and a fan, and arent stuck in a tight space.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually a small icon that appears in the top right corner for overheating (and another for under-voltage)

Comment: This should really be comment on the question as you are essentially asking them for clarification about their question.

Comment: Yes Darth, I agree. However, Stack Exchange deems me unable to comment on a question until I reach a 'level', but can comment on comments!